# What do I need to do to get my Apple Watch apps to show current data?

Tags: data-synchronization, apple-watch

For most of my apps, when I launch them on my Apple Watch (that is, *once they actually launch*), I see old data (sometimes weeks old). For example the OpenTable watch app does not seem show any reservations I've made since last launching the OpenTable app on my iPhone. Is this the intended behavior of the Apple Watch OS, or is it simply a programming error on the part of the app developer? Or is there something I need to do to ensure that Apple Watch apps show current data?

What do I need to do to get my Apple Watch apps to show current data?

Comment: Do you have background-updates enabled for all the apps on your iPhone?

Comment: Wether the app pulls data itself or from the iPhone is for the developer to decide AFAIK

Comment: @KevinGrabher: Do you mean "Background App Refresh"? If so, yes, where possible; but many apps that show old data (e.g. OpenTable) don't even have a setting for "Background App Refresh".

Comment: Okay, well that has been my only idea to be honest. Unfortunately Austria isn't important enough to get the Apple Watch yet >:| so you'll have to wait on other (happier) people to help.

Comment: @KevinGrabher: Here's hoping that by the time it reaches Austria it (and the third party apps, if that's the issue here) is out of beta!

Comment: This borders on too broad IMO. Could you edit this to focus on one app and document specific timings? How can we tell if your expectations are if you don't document them. Also, try to have one question per question. I count three questions in the initial phrasing of this post.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - I got a watch from germany via ebay. I've had it for 2 days and I can confirm that refreshes are dodgy. Sometimes they work like a charm, other times I have to open the iPhone app (which needs to refresh itself first as well). So the problem really is that sometimes apps don't background-refresh on the phone (which I suppose should be forced by opening them on the watch).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I'll force-close the app and that gets things to refresh. This is done by pressing and holding the side button until the power off settings appear. Then let go and press and hold the side button again until the settings disappear and the app closes. Hope that helps!